# Inserting multiple elements of one array into another (Inserting those elements starting at an index)

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array which has 3 elements [0, 4, 0] and I have another array of elements [1, 2, 3]. I am trying to insert those 3 elements (1, 2, 3) at the first 0 of my first array, so the outcome is this: [1, 2, 3, 4, 0] and then I have a third array consisting of elements [5, 6, 7] which I am trying to insert at the last 0, so the final outcome is: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]. Any ideas?

```
public static int[] depositElements(int[] from, int[] to, int index) {
    int originalIndex = index;
    int[] newArray = new int[(to.length + from.length) - 1];
    for(int i = 0; i < from.length; i++) {
        newArray[index++] = from[i];
    }
    //System.arraycopy(to, originalIndex + 1, newArray, originalIndex + (from.length), to.length - 1);
    System.out.println("NEWARRAY: "+Arrays.toString(newArray));
    return newArray;
}
```

Here's the code which uses that above method:

```
boolean looped = false;
int[] old = objectIds;
for(int j = 0; j < multipleObjects.size(); j++) {
    Integer[] mObjects = multipleObjects.get(j);
    System.out.println("New ObjectIds in the MultipleObjects Cache: "+Arrays.toString(mObjects));
    if(!looped) {
        for(int i = 0; i < objectIds.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
            if(objectIds[i] == 0) {
                int[] newArray = ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(multipleObjects.get(j++));
                System.out.println("At "+i+" "+Arrays.toString(newArray));
                old = ArrayUtils.depositElements(newArray, old, ArrayUtils.indexOf(old, 0));
                System.out.println("Old is currently: "+old.length+" "+Arrays.toString(old));
            }
            if(i == objectIds.length - 1) {
                System.out.println("Looped once.");
                looped = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("OLD OBJECT IDS: "+Arrays.toString(old));
System.out.println("ObjectIds Array: "+Arrays.toString(objectIds));
```

Comment: What is the problem? Could you give us sample input, your expected output, and the actual output?

Comment: My expected output is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] but my actual output is [1, 2, 3, 0, 0]

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out by myself.

Answer (score 0):

You never copy any values from the `to` array into `newArray`. You need to copy both the elements preceding the index and the elements following the contents of the `from` array.

Comment: That's my question. I tried doing System.arrayCopy but it ends up with NPE.

Comment: What do you mean by "have no luck"? The results of executing System.arrayCopy() do not depend on anyone's luck.

Comment: I'm sorry, I phrased that wrong. Meant it ends up with a NPE.

Answer (score 0):

If the instantiated array, [0, 4, 0] is preset, you can just replace the array's 0th and 2nd index with the other array information (I.E. from.length[0]) which it seems you never copy the values over.

Comment: Yeah I realized that, but that's what I need help with, haha.

Comment: Use the array.indexOf() method to search for which index you're attempting to replace. Example: `array.indexOf(0)` and `array.indexOf(2)` would find the indexes you need, then just replace those indexes with the other instantiated arrays via an if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to keep values of the `to[]` array, you have to make sure to keep the track of the remaining values (after replacing) in that array. This depends on the `index`. In order to do this you can divide the problem in two, by using a branch:

1. If your index **is '0'**, then with a little bit change in your `depositElements` method implementation (using the originalIndex variable) you can have the result.
2. If your index **is not the first one in the array**, then you should keep the first part of the array and then add the new values so again you need to use the `originalIndex` variable because the index itself changes during the code.

This is how you can implement your code:

```
    public static int[] depositElements(int[] from, int[] to, int index) {
    int originalIndex = index;
    int[] newArray = new int[(to.length + from.length) - 1];

    if (index == 0) {

        for(int i = 0; i < from.length; i++) {
            newArray[index++] = from[i];
        }
        newArray[ from.length ] = to[ originalIndex + 1 ];

    } else {

        int j = 0;
        while ( j<originalIndex ) {
            newArray[j] = to[j];
            j++;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i<from.length; i++) {
            newArray[ index++ ] = from[i];
        }
    }
    //System.arraycopy(to, originalIndex + 1, newArray, originalIndex + (from.length), to.length - 1);
    System.out.println("NEWARRAY: "+Arrays.toString(newArray));
    return newArray;
}
```